# Make nginx to redirect every request to index.php but not download files

Tags: php, nginx

I tried to setup nginx to redirect every request to index.php and it kinda works, problem is if i go to to /task which is php file without extension it downloads it.
My server block looks like this:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

It redirects everything to index.php except that one file. How do i make it to not download it?

Comment: I think you can another location:

location /task {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/task;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

previous to the main location. But I not sure if its the better solution

Comment: The goal here is to just let that file sit there ignored, not downloaded, not execute  from browser, it is basically command line script

Comment: There is nothing in your configuration that would cause the behaviour you are describing. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to ensure that the configuration that Nginx is reading is consistent with your question, and ensure that you clear the browser's cache between tests.

Comment: it happens only when this file is without extension, if i make it task.php, it will not download it and redirects to index.php